# "Run Command" file editing (i.e. " *.rc " files): Echoing to the terminal like Linux?

Tags: android, linux, shell, rc

I am editing the Android phone file "init.tuna.rc" so that it prints to me some basic debugging checkpoint messages so I can analyze how far the phone gets in the boot process.

Does anyone know if you can simply insert the shell scripting syntax for console printing into a "run command" file (.rc)?

(I need to know this if someone can help me before I rebuild all of my code for the Android tree to test this debugging code, given the process can a while)

Will the following work?  I want to insert in the following code snippet into the "init.tuna.rc" file:

```
# Boot debugging Checkpoint #2
echo "Check #2:  Successfully wrote the file system data, including the wifi directories!"
```

If this does not work, what can I do to get the "rc" file to print messages to the actual terminal as it executes?

Comment: The rc at the end of a file is related to the phrase "run commands"; its use derives from the /etc/rc.* files used to start most Unix systems. The rc suffix is commonly used for any file that contains startup information for a program. Common rc files include .newsrc, .pinerc, and .cshrc.

Comment: So then, do you know if you can edit these kinds of start-up info files to also print to the console?  They seem to remind me of something like a script, which I know you can use "echo" in.  I imagine whatever is parsing this information file, reads from top to bottom and executes commands accordingly in order, right?

Comment: No, just about to, but I wanted to find out if anyone knew before I went through rebuilding my code to try this.  Even with the optimization I set up for rebuilds, it can still a while to rebuild.

Comment: Note:  This does not work.  So much for any useful debugging to figure out why a phone doesn't boot!

Answer (score 1):

**Android Boot Language** is documented in a `readme.txt` file in the source tree under `<android>/system/core/init`.
No `echo` is mentioned, but you can try. Also remember that you should write to a file because stderr and stdout are redirected to `/dev/null`.

See https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/README.md

Comment: Note:  "echo" does not work.  And cannot, after I failed in trying, b/c I realized that echo would only send something to the phone's file system not the external computer.